# what the meaning of histogram of silhouette?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, histogram, feature-descriptor, silhouette

I know the silhouette is the person body that we get it using for example background subtraction. but what is the histogram of silhouette and what the benefit of it.

since I 've read in many papers that they are used the histogram of silhouette as a feature for recognition.

Thanks for your cooperation,

Regards

Comment: Are you referring to the histogram of the pixel values or the histogram of some other feature ? More context needed.

Comment: I have read in some papers that they used histogram of silhouette features to benefit from in their system. actually, I did not understand what are they meant by histogram of silhouette features??

Comment: neither do I, this is not a common term. Refer to those papers and provide more context.

Comment: what about on what you said the (histogram of pixel value)??

Comment: could someone explain the meaning of that??